# Let $(G,<)$ be an archimedean left-ordered group, then $\exists H \in (\mathbb{R},<)$ and $ (G,<) \cong (H,<)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Here is the proof in the book:
[image]

How do we show that $\phi(g)$ converges?

My attempt: 
Let $ \phi_k(g)=\frac{a_{2^k}}{2^k}$, then $|\phi_{k+1}(g)-\phi_k(g)|=|\frac{a_{2^{k+1}}}{2^{k+1}}-\frac{a_{2^k}}{2^k}|=|\frac{a_{2^{k+1}}-2a_{2^k}}{2^{k+1}}|$

Comment: Do you know that the ordering of an Archimedean left-ordered group is also right-invariant? Or that such groups are abelian?

Comment: yes I proved it before

Comment: Actually I can show that the $\phi_k$ converge, but I've not yet managed to show that $a_n/n$ also does.